# How do I choose an SD card for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: hardware, sd-card, compatibility, purchasing

When looking to purchase an SD card for a Raspberry Pi, what sort of considerations need to be taken into account?

Are there certain cards that won't work with the system, or should all standard SD cards work? Is there a max SD card size (for instance, will a 128GB SDXC work with the device) or are there size limitations?

What sort of speed capacities are required in order to run an OS from the card, and how do I know if the SD card will be fast enough?

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sd-cards.md http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals

Comment: pay attention to READ/WRITE Cycles of the SD card. SanDisk, is notoriously low (10K Writes). Where other SD cards have +1M Writes per block.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is speed: this is what boots the OS, I'd say that at least a Class 10 SD, modern Linux really works best with at least 8GB, although 4 is possible. A MicroSD card with a half height adapter is preferred,as the regular SD slot sticks out. 
It really depends what your doing with the RPI. 
[Here is a list of cards,etc.](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards)